# JQGrid Dynamic Row Editable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I have created a JqGrid with my custom data and using formatters.

where if i click on some text(ex: "D") i have to change the text some other text (ex: "R"). as well as the background colors.

**scenario is like this :**

- user clicks the A, cell changes to a C
- user clicks the D, cell changes to an R
- user clicks the R, cell changes to a D
- user clicks the C, cell changes to an A

**JS CODE :**

```
    function SalesOptimizationGridData() {
    var mydata =[ { size: "S1", op: "170", OPStatus: "X", s1: "-170", S1Status: "C", s2: "170", S2Status: "D", s3: "170", S3Status: "A", s4: "170", S4Status: "C", s5: "170", S5Status: "C" },
{ size: "S2", op: "-170", OPStatus: "D", s1: "-170", S1Status: "C", s2: "-170", S2Status: "X", s3: "-170", S3Status: "D", s4: "-170", S4Status: "C", s5: "-170", S5Status: "D" },
{ size: "S3", op: "370", OPStatus: "X", s1: "370", S1Status: "C", s2: "-370", S2Status: "A", s3: "-370", S3Status: "C", s4: "370", S4Status: "C", s5: "-370", S5Status: "A" },
{ size: "S4", op: "-270", OPStatus: "D", s1: "-170", S1Status: "D", s2: "-170", S2Status: "R", s3: "170", S3Status: "C", s4: "170", S4Status: "A", s5: "170", S5Status: "R" },
{ size: "S5", op: "-340", OPStatus: "X", s1: "170", S1Status: "R", s2: "270", S2Status: "A", s3: "-170", S3Status: "D", s4: "340", S4Status: "D", s5: "-170", S5Status: "A" },
{ size: "S6", op: "-140", OPStatus: "A", s1: "-270", S1Status: "R", s2: "170", S2Status: "A", s3: "170", S3Status: "C", s4: "170", S4Status: "R", s5: "170", S5Status: "C" },
{ size: "S7", op: "-140", OPStatus: "C", s1: "-170", S1Status: "D", s2: "170", S2Status: "D", s3: "-170", S3Status: "R", s4: "240", S4Status: "X", s5: "170", S5Status: "C" },
{ size: "S8", op: "0", OPStatus: "X", s1: "-0", S1Status: " ", s2: "0", S2Status: "D", s3: "0", s4: "0", S3Status: "C", S4Status: "A", s5: "0", S5Status: "X" },
{ size: "S9", op: "170", OPStatus: "R", s1: "170", S1Status: "X", s2: "170", S2Status: "D", s3: "170", S3Status: "A", S4Status: "C", s4: "170", s5: "-170", S5Status: "D" },


    ];
    return mydata;
} 
function AssortmentDetailsGrid() {
    $("#ao-salesoptimization-grid").jqGrid({
        data: SalesOptimizationGridData(),
        datatype: "local",
        autowidth: false,
        //shrinkToFit: true,
        rowNum: 15,
        rowList: [15, 30, 45],
        colNames: ['SIZE', 'OP', 'S1', 'S2',  'S3',  'S4', 'S5'],
        colModel: [
            {
              name: 'size', index: 'id', sortable: true, sorttype: 'int', resizable: true},
            { name: 'op', index: 'op', sortable: true, sorttype: 'int', resizable: true, formatter: opformatter },
            { name: 's1', index: 's1', sortable: true, sorttype: 'int', resizable: true, formatter: s1formatter },
            { name: 's2', index: 's2', sortable: true, sorttype: 'string', resizable: true, formatter: s2formatter },
            { name: 's3', index: 's3', sortable: true, sorttype: 'string', resizable: true, formatter: s3formatter },
            { name: 's4', index: 's4', sortable: true, sorttype: 'int', resizable: true, formatter: s4formatter },
            { name: 's5', index: 's5', formatter: s5formatter }
        ],
        sortname: 'id',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        loadOnce: true,
        gridview: true,
        loadComplete: function () {
            if ($("#ao-salesoptimization-grid-container").width() !== 0)
                $('#ao-assortmentdetails-grid').setGridWidth($("#ao-salesoptimization-grid-container").width());
            InitjQueryScroll();
            $("#gview_ao-salesoptimization-grid").find('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').mCustomScrollbar({ theme: "rounded" });


            if ($(".ao-op-grid-formatter:first-child > p").text() === "D") {
                $(".ao-op-grid-formatter").addClass("statusD");
            }
        }


    });
    function opformatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<div class="ao-op-grid-formatter"><p>' + rowObject.OPStatus + '</p></div>' + ' ' + '<div class="ao-grid-formatter">' + cellvalue + '</div>';
        //return cellvalue;
    }

    function s1formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<div class="ao-op-grid-formatter"><p>' + rowObject.S1Status + '</p></div>' + ' ' + '<div class="ao-grid-formatter">' + cellvalue + '</div>';
        //return cellvalue;
    }

    function s2formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<div class="ao-op-grid-formatter"><p>' + rowObject.S2Status + '</p></div>' + ' ' + '<div class="ao-grid-formatter">' + cellvalue + '</div>';
        //return cellvalue;
    }
    function s3formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<div class="ao-op-grid-formatter"><p>' + rowObject.S3Status + '</p></div>' + ' ' + '<div class="ao-grid-formatter">' + cellvalue + '</div>';
        //return cellvalue;
    }
    function s4formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<div class="ao-op-grid-formatter"><p>' + rowObject.S4Status + '</p></div>' + ' ' + '<div class="ao-grid-formatter">' + cellvalue + '</div>';
        //return cellvalue;
    }
    function s5formatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
        return '<div class="ao-op-grid-formatter"><p>' + rowObject.S5Status + '</p></div>' + ' ' + '<div class="ao-grid-formatter">' + cellvalue + '</div>';
        //return cellvalue;
    }


}
```

Working JSFIDDLE is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/sarav4gs/bngscfmv/)

Kindy help me if you have any idea!! thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd recommend you to simplify `colModel` and to use **one** formatter for all columns:

```
colModel: [
    { name: 'size', key: true }, // ??? sorttype: 'int' - see non int values "S8", "S1", ...
    { name: 'op', sorttype: 'int', formatter: statusFormatter },
    { name: 's1', sorttype: 'int', formatter: statusFormatter },
    { name: 's2', formatter: statusFormatter },
    { name: 's3', formatter: statusFormatter },
    { name: 's4', sorttype: 'int', formatter: statusFormatter },
    { name: 's5', formatter: statusFormatter }
]
```

where `statusFormatter` could be defined like

```
function statusFormatter(cellvalue, options, rowObject) {
    var status = rowObject[options.colModel.name.toUpperCase() + "Status"] || " ";
    return '<div class="ao-op-grid-formatter' + (status === "D" ? ' statusD"' : '"') +
         '><p>' + status +
        '</p></div>' + ' ' + '<div class="ao-grid-formatter">' + cellvalue + '</div>';
}
```

The statement `$(".ao-op-grid-formatter").addClass("statusD");` can be removed from `loadComplete`.

To change the status of the data and the corresponding content in the grid you can use `beforeSelectRow` callback. The corresponding code could be about the following

```
beforeSelectRow: function (rowid, e) {
    var $self = $(this), cmName, status,
        item = $self.jqGrid("getLocalRow", rowid),
        $td = $(e.target).closest("tr.jqgrow>td"),
        iCol = $td.length > 0 ? $td[0].cellIndex : -1,
        p = $self.jqGrid("getGridParam");
    if ($(e.target).is(".ao-op-grid-formatter>p") && iCol>0 && p.colModel[iCol]!=null) {
        cmName = p.colModel[iCol].name;
        status = item[cmName.toUpperCase() + "Status"];
        switch (status) {
            case "A":
                status = "C";
                break;
            case "D":
                status = "R";
                break;
            case "R":
                status = "D";
                break;
            case "C":
                status = "A";
                break;
            default:
                //status = " ";
                break;
        }
        item[cmName.toUpperCase() + "Status"] = status;
        $(e.target).text(status);
        if (status === "D") {
            $(e.target).parent().addClass("statusD");
        } else {
            $(e.target).parent().removeClass("statusD");
        }
    }
},
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/bngscfmv/4/

Comment: @IamSarav: One more remark. I see that you are member on stackoverflow since 22 months and used voting only 4 times. Voting is one of the most important right on the stackovrflow. Google and other searching engine uses the voting count for sorting the searching results. The more users vote the question/answer up the more easy it will be to find. You have right to vote **30 answers and questions per day**. Please use it on *any helpful information*, which you find on stackoverflow (not only answers on your questions). You helps other peoples of the communicate in the way.

Comment: oh sure, i will be doing it from now on :) thanks for the info